# The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column but SELECT MAX(A) FROM t WHERE a>1000 returns NULL why?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Table T exists with single column A having 4 rows with values – 100, 200, NULL, 300.

What is the output of the following query?

```
SELECT MAX(A) FROM t WHERE a>1000;
```

The options are:

- 300
- NULL
- No rows
- Error is thrown

The correct answer is NULL. My interpretation is the query should return No rows but right answer is NUll.

Can someone please explain me?

Comment: NULL is the right answer because there is no row greater than (a>1000) 1000 and its a system defined answer.it will never return No rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` condition does not satisfy any rows in the table, so

```
select a
from t
where a > 1000;
```

returns no rows.

However, the maximum value of "nothing" is `NULL`.

In SQL, `NULL` is the absence of information. It's the natural choice when the database can't find data.

Aggregates like `max()`, `min()` or `count()` will always return exactly one row if used without a `GROUP BY`

Comment: That make sense. Thank you for the answer and editing the question @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

NULL is the right answer. MAX can not return zero rows. NULL is appropriate because there are no rows > 1000.